# How to convert numbers to words python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I have an issue when trying to convert numbers to words: it crashes when I enter 80, or if i enter 100 it produces "one hundred two hundred". Can someone help me fix my code.

```
number = input("Enter a value: ")
ones = ["", "one ", "two ","three ", "four", "five ", "six ", "seven ", 
"eight ", "nine "]
teens = ["ten ", "eleven ", "twelve ", "thirteen ", "fourteen ", "fifteen ", 
"sixteen ", "seventeen ", "eighteen ", "nineteen "]
decades = ["", "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ", "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy 
", "eighty ", "ninety "]
hundreds = ["", "one hundred ", "two hundred ", "three hundred ", "four 
hundred ", "five hundred", "six hundred ", "seven hundred", "eight hundred", 
"nine hundred"]

word = ""
change = len(number)

while change > 0:
    if number == "0":
        word ="zero"
        break
    elif change > 1 and number[change - 2] == "1":
        for i in range(0,10):
            if number[change - 1] == str(i):
                word = teens[i] + word
    else:
        for i in range(0,10):
            if number[change - 1] == str(i):
                word = ones[i] + word
    if change > 1:
        for i in range(0,10):
            if number[change - 2] == str(i):
                word = decades[i] + word
    if change > 2:
        for i in range(0,10):
            if number[change - 3] == str(i):
                word = hundreds[i] + word
    change = change - 3
print(word)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work: [word2number](https://pypi.org/project/word2number/)

And an example from their docs: 
`print(w2n.word_to_num('one hundred thirty-five'))`

Comment: I don't think OP wants to use a library.

Comment: @Yasen I do not want to use a library for this applications, thanks though

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a comma between "seventy" and "eighty" in decades. You have to change decades to the following:

```
decades = ["", "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ", "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy", "eighty ", "ninety"]
```

The same mistake is there in hunderds list as well. Use this new list:

```
hundreds = ["", "one hundred ", "two hundred ", "three hundred ", "four hundred ", "five hundred", "six hundred ", "seven hundred", "eight hundred", "nine hundred"]
```

Nevertheless, your implementation has lot of mistakes.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, when I enter 80, it is returning 90 and I am unsure as to why if you could help.

Comment: @WhiteFlower Use: word = decades[i-1] + word

Comment: @ErnestSKirubakaran Thanks, I have updated the comma mistakes. I have tried implementing this, however when i enter 95 it returns "five".

Comment: @WhiteFlower As I said, there are lot of mistakes. You need to think about the structure of your code again

Answer (score 0):

Just this if statements will work (note that's all you need to make it work):

```
if len(number)==1:
   print(ones[int(number)])
elif len(number)==2 and number[0]=='1':
   print(teens[int(number[-1])])
elif len(number)==2 and number[0]!='1':
   print(decades[int(number[0])-1])
elif len(number)==3:
   print(hundreds[int(number[0])])
```

Note that have to add commas in `decades` and `hundreds`, so copy the below, then replace with the clipboard:

```
decades = ["", "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ", "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy", "eighty ", "ninety "]
hundreds = ["", "one hundred ", "two hundred ", "three hundred ", "four hundred ", "five hundred", "six hundred ", "seven hundred", "eight hundred",
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I have tried this it works only for certain cases like 80, 10, 5 etc but if i try 153 or 86 etc it just returns "one hundred" or "eighty".

Answer (score 0):

I think that for making your example working you just need to make sure that each `change` digit is accessing the correct value in your lists. That's not the case for your `decades` lists, where you missed a blank string for the teens, that you're correctly treating as a separate case.

So to make your code work just change:

```
decades = ["", "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ", "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy", "eighty ", "ninety "]
```

to this:

```
decades = ["", "", "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ", "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy", "eighty ", "ninety "]
```

Answer (score 0):

For this implementation, you should always have 10 elements in the lists. For example, in decades you should have some string representing the values between 10-20 even if its not used because the indexing of the array would be wrong otherwise.

Still this code has a lot of mistakes.
Try this.

```
number = input("Enter a value: ")
ones = ["", "one ", "two ","three ", "four", "five ", "six ", "seven ", "eight ", "nine "]
teens = ["ten ", "eleven ", "twelve ", "thirteen ", "fourteen ", "fifteen ", "sixteen ", "seventeen ", "eighteen ", "nineteen "]
decades = ["", "onety", "twenty ", "thirty ", "forty ", "fifty ", "sixty ", "seventy ", "eighty ", "ninety "]
hundreds = ["", "one hundred ", "two hundred ", "three hundred ", "four hundred ", "five hundred", "six hundred ", "seven hundred", "eight hundred", "nine hundred"]

word = ""
change = len(number)

while change > 0:
    if number == "0":
        word ="zero"
        break
    elif change > 1 and number[change - 2] == "1":
        for i in range(0,10):
            if number[change - 1] == str(i):
                word = teens[i] + word
        if change == 2:
            break
    else:
        for i in range(0,10):
            if number[change - 1] == str(i):
                word = ones[i] + word
    if change > 1 and number[change-2]!="1":
        for i in range(0,10):
            if number[change - 2] == str(i):
                word = decades[i] + word
    if change > 2:
        for i in range(0,10):
            if number[change - 3] == str(i):
                word = hundreds[i] + word
    change = change - 3
print(word)
```